# Comparing and setting select dropdown values

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select dropdowns with a range of price values. The first is labelled "Price From" and the second is labelled 'Price To". I created an event listener to determine when the "Price From" value has changed and within this event listener I want to check if the selected value is larger than the "Price To" valie. If it is, then change the "Price To" value to a value larger than the "Price From" value. Otherwise do nothng.

Here is the HTML.

The "Price From" HTML:

```
<select id="price_from">
    <option selected value="0">Any</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="7000">7000</option>
    <option value="8000">8000</option>
    <option value="9000">9000</option>
    <option value="10000">10 000</option>
    <option value="12500">12 500</option>
    <option value="15000">15 000</option>
    <option value="17500">17 500</option>
    <option value="20000">20 000</option>
    .
    .                                   
</select>
```

The "Price To" HTML:

```
<select id="price_to">
    <option selected value="100000">Any</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
    <option value="7500">7500</option>
    <option value="10000">10 000</option>
    <option value="12500">12 500</option>
    <option value="15000">15 000</option>
    <option value="17500">17 500</option>
    <option value="20000">20 000</option>
    <option value="22500">22 500</option>
    .
    .
    .                                           
</select>
```

The event listener I described above:

```
document.getElementById("price_from").addEventListener("change", function(){

    var price_to_select = document.getElementById("price_to"); //The "Price To" select dropdown
    var price_to = price_to_select.value; //Get the current "Price To" value

    var price_from = this.value; //Get the current "Price From" value

    if(price_from >= price_to){ //Compare values
        //Loop through "Price To" values and as soon as a larger value than current 
        //"Price From" value has been found, set that value as the current "Price To" value
        for(var k=1; k<price_to_select.length; k++ ){ 
            price_to_k_value = price_to_select.options[k].value;

            if(price_to_k_value>price_from){
                price_to_select.value = price_to_k_value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

All of this works, except for when the "Price To" value gets larger than 10000.

For example. If I set "Price To" to 3000 and the "Price From" to 4000, the "Price To" is correctly set to 5000. However, as soon as I set "Price To" to 7500 and the "Price From" to 8000, I expect the "Price To" to be set to 10000, but it doesn't.

Note: I start the for counter at `k=1`, because I do not want to include the first value with label "Any".

Comment: Feedback - @Mr Polywhirl answered the question. Thank you. However, the fact that someone downvoted the question reminds me why I don't visit SO often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make sure you are checking for integer comparison vs string comparison.

To test this, make sure you set a "to" value first, then start changing the "from" to a higher value.

```js
document.getElementById('sel-price-from').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let fromVal = parseValue(e.target.value);
  let selTo = document.getElementById('sel-price-to');
  let toVal = parseValue(selTo.value);
  if (toVal < fromVal) {
    let opts = selTo.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (let i = 1; i < opts.length; i++) {
      let value = parseValue(opts[i].value);
      if (value > fromVal) {
        selTo.value = value
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});

function parseValue(value) {
  return parseInt(value.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10);
}
```

```html
<label>Price from: </label>
<select id="sel-price-from">
  <option selected value="0">Any</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="3000">3000</option>
  <option value="4000">4000</option>
  <option value="5000">5000</option>
  <option value="6000">6000</option>
  <option value="7000">7000</option>
  <option value="8000">8000</option>
  <option value="9000">9000</option>
  <option value="10000">10 000</option>
  <option value="12500">12 500</option>
  <option value="15000">15 000</option>
  <option value="17500">17 500</option>
  <option value="20000">20 000</option>
</select>
<label>Price to: </label>
<select id="sel-price-to">
  <option selected value="100000">Any</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="3000">3000</option>
  <option value="4000">4000</option>
  <option value="5000">5000</option>
  <option value="7500">7500</option>
  <option value="10000">10 000</option>
  <option value="12500">12 500</option>
  <option value="15000">15 000</option>
  <option value="17500">17 500</option>
  <option value="20000">20 000</option>
  <option value="22500">22 500</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need `parseInt()`:

```js
if (parseInt(price_to_k_value) > parseInt(price_from)) {
    // etc.
}
```